# confusion in weakly connected space definition

Tags: general-topology

Taken from [here see  definition $2$](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Weakly_Locally_Connected_at_Point)

Here  is an outine of definition $2$

The space $T$ is weakly locally connected at $x$ if and only if every open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ contains an open neighborhood $V$ of $x$ such that **every two points** of $V$ lie in some connected subset of $U.$

My confusion is that  why  two every points of $V$ had mentioned in definition ? why not only one point?

In  Munkres book   it is written that a space $X$ is said to be weakly locally connected at $x$ if for every neighborhood $U$ of $x$, there is a connected subspace of $X$ contained in $U$ that contains
a neighborhood of $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first definition implies the final Munkres one:

Let $U$ be a neighbourhood of $x$. Let $V$ be an open neighbourhood of $x$ such that each pair of points from $V$ lie in some connected set contained in $\operatorname{int}(U)$ (applying the first definition to the open neighbourhood $\operatorname{int}(U)$ of $x$). For any $y \in V$ let $C(x,y) \subseteq \operatorname{int}(U)$ be such a connected set. Then, as all these connected sets  intersect in $x$, we can define $V' = \bigcup \{C(x,y): y \in V\}$ and know that $V'$ is connected and as it contains $V$, it is a neighbourhood of $x$ too, and $V' \subseteq \operatorname{int}(U)$ is also clear. This $V'$ is then the connected subspace of $X$ contained in $U$ that contains a neighbourhood of $x$.

Then the Munkres definition at the end implies the first definition : if $U$ is an open neighbourhood of $x$ we find a connected $C\subseteq U$ such that $C$ contains a neighbourhood of $x$. But then $V= \operatorname{int}(C)$ is as required for the first definition: just $C$ as the required set for every pair of points from $V$.

So these definitions define the  same class of spaces ("connected im kleinen" with an English/German term, as is the more common name).

Comment: ..@Henno sir  can we  take  $C(x,y)= B(x,\epsilon)? $  i mean $ C(x,y)$ as  an open ball

Comment: @jasmine no, not necessarily.